# "callback is not the function" and function.apply()

Tags: javascript, callback

Why this simply doesn't work?

It says typeof(callback) = undefined.

```
function A(a,callback)
{
document.write(typeof(callback));  
callback();  
return a;  
}

function Run(func,args)
{

   return  func.apply(this||window, args || [
    function () { document.write("blah")}
  ]);

}


Run(A,[1]);
```

However, without using function.apply it works properly:

```
function Run2(func,arg)
{

   return  func(arg,
    function () { document.write("blah")}
  );

}

Run2(A,1);
```

Please be patient I'm new to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is the scope, while the second is an array of arguments. It appears you have this, but `args` with `Run(A,[1]);` is only a single argument (1) which will be aligned with the `a` parameter, however you're **missing** the function. On the other hand, if `args` is not set, you're opting to create an array with a single argument of `[ function ()... ]`, which will again will be aligned with `a`.

From the looks of it, you're attempting to merge/concatenate the two arrays, when in fact `||` is used as a comparison operator, or rather an `or` assignment.

Try this:

```
func.apply(this||window,args.concat([function () { document.write("blah")}]));
```

or

```
args.push(function () { document.write("blah")});
func.apply(this||window,args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually occuring in the `A` function with the `callback` variable. If you had written the `A` function as below you will not receive this error:

```
function A(a, callback) {
    var type = typeof callback;
    document.write(type);
    if(type == "function") callback();//ensure callback is a function
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` takes the first argument and uses it as `this` in the function call, and uses the second argument as the arguments to that call.  So Run2 is calling A like this (where `<func>` is your anonymous function):

```
A(1, <func>);
```

Run is only passing the one argument in your argument array, `1` and calling it like this:

```
A(1)
```

What you want to do is replace your Run with this (I think):

```
function Run(func,args)
{
    args.push(function () { document.write("blah")});
    // args is now [1, function(){...}]
    return func.apply(this||window, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need an Array length of 2 for your `Run()` function to work using `A()`, because it takes two arguments. You just have 1 in args, as `[1]`. You want `[1, func]`, so the following would be your solution:

```
// the keyword this always exists
function Run(func, args){
  args.push(func);
  return  func.apply(this, args || [function(){document.write("blah")}]);
}
```